# Testing for daylight saving time within Cocoa and CocoaTouch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unit-testing, nsdate

I am developing a calendar application that needs to draw rectangles whose heights and vertical position are based on the start date of the event they represent. I am trying to test the layout system against dates and time zones with daylight saving. Specifically I want to account for the fact that in some regions daylight saving can remove/add an hour to the day.

Currently I'm stumped on how to write unit tests against daylight saving time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [NSTimeZone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTimeZone) class reference. It has a handy `BOOL` property called `-daylightSavingTime` [and related friends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000190-SW16) you may find useful. You can [create a date with a specific time zone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-SW4) / date combination to get what you need and feed that instead of the system-provided time.

I'm not sure there's a way to change the system time (even in the simulator) programmatically, however. I haven't attempted anything like this but perhaps a creative use of some preprocessor macros and/or environment variables could let you toggle between test states.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I'll combine your answer with swizzling and all my methods that call `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` should have the time zone I need to use.